# How to deserialize XML into an object?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to convert an XML doc (invoiceList) into an object. Ideally I'd like to convert it into a collection of objects ("Invoices").

Below is a fragment of the XML. I've also included a fragment off my INVOICE object. And finally my attempt at deserialization. The error message I get is so useless that I don't know where to start.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <invoiceListResponse>
       <invoiceList>
         <invoiceListItem>
            <invoiceUid>39165890</invoiceUid>
            <lastUpdatedUid>AAAAADrKwis=</lastUpdatedUid>
            <ccy>JPY</ccy>
            <autoPopulateFXRate>false</autoPopulateFXRate>
            <fcToBcFxRate>1.0000000000</fcToBcFxRate>
            <transactionType>S</transactionType>
            <invoiceDate>2013-12-26</invoiceDate>
            <utcFirstCreated>2013-12-26T08:12:22</utcFirstCreated>
            <utcLastModified>2013-12-26T08:12:22</utcLastModified>
            <summary />
            <invoiceNumber>W101010101</invoiceNumber>
```

fragment of Invoice object code

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "invoice")]
public class InvoiceDto : TransactionDto
{
    public InvoiceDto()
    {
        TradingTerms = new TradingTermsDto();
        QuickPayment = new QuickPaymentDto();
    }

    public InvoiceDto(string transactionType, string layout)
    {
        Layout = layout;
        TransactionType = transactionType;
        TradingTerms = new TradingTermsDto();
        QuickPayment = new QuickPaymentDto();
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "transactionType")]
    public string TransactionType;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoiceType")]
    public string InvoiceType;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "contactUid")]
    public int          ContactUid;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "shipToContactUid")]
    public int ShipToContactUid;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "externalNotes")]
    public string ExternalNotes;
```

My code:

```
Dim list As XmlDocument = proxy.Find(queries)
'Deserialize text file to a new object. 
    Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(list.InnerXml))
      reader.MoveToContent()
      reader.Read()
      reader.Read()
      theinv = DirectCast(New XmlSerializer(GetType(Dto.InvoiceDto)).Deserialize(reader), Dto.InvoiceDto)
      Debug.Write(theinv.InvoiceNumber)
```

Error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: There is an error in XML document (1, 74).

Comment: It's been a long time since I've made a serialisation, but I think it might be a tag mismatch. Your class expect a tag called "invoice", while in the XML it states "<invoiceListItem>". Have you tried to make these 2 the same?

Comment: your class in C# and your code in VB ?

Comment: yes, class was provided by a vendor. Consuming application is a VB app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to create a class that matches the *entire* XML document from its root level down.  It doesn't need to contain a property for every node, but it needs to at least contain a property for each element in the path to get from the root element down to the ones that you care about.  For instance, the following class will work to load the document in your example:

```
[XmlRoot("invoiceListResponse")]
public class InvoiceListResponse
{

    [XmlArray("invoiceList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("invoiceListItem")]
    public InvoiceDto[] InvoiceList;
}
```

Then, you can deserialize into it like this:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InvoiceListResponse));
using (FileStream f = new FileStream("Test.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    InvoiceListResponse response = (InvoiceListResponse)s.Deserialize(f);
}
```

**Edit**

Based on your comments, below, it appears that what you need to do is to deserialize into that exact DTO class, without making any modifications to it.  If that is the case, and you don't want to create a wrapper class as I demonstrated in my first example, you could always do something like this:

```
Dim invoices As New List(Of InvoiceDto)()
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(InvoiceDto))
For Each i As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/invoiceListResponse/invoiceList/invoiceListItem")
    Using reader As New StringReader("<invoice>" & i.InnerXml & "</invoice>")
        invoices.Add(DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), InvoiceDto))
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. I see the Invoice class provided is intended for a REST call which returns an individual invoice object, but I'd like to use it to contain the invoices from a returned InvoiceList. Perhaps I'll just need to create an entirely new class for this purpose as you suggest. But I worry I'm going to get stuck with the embedded Item ArrayList. Too bad there isn't anyway to contact most people here on stack for contract work!

Comment: I guess rather than create a class that matches all my xml elements, I could also remove the ones I don't need via xmlDocument before I start the deserialization huh?

Comment: I added an example of how you could do something like that.